# gwt upgrade from version 2.7 to 2.8

Tags: gwt

I am developing an application with gwt.
Until now I used gwt version 2.7.
But now I decided to upgrade to version 2.8. 
I downloaded gwt 2.8 from http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html
and replaced the version in eclipse.
After I ran the application (in super dev mode) and during the application compile, I get this error:

```
 [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:111)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:331)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:139)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:135)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:786)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:778)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:896)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1410)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.doCompile(Recompiler.java:362)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:175)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.recompile(Recompiler.java:134)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.recompile(Outbox.java:135)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.recompile(JobRunner.java:113)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.access$000(JobRunner.java:37)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner$2.run(JobRunner.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/ext/typeinfo/HasMetaData
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.hasTag(JSWrapperGenerator.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.TaskFactory$WrapperPolicy.shouldConstruct(TaskFactory.java:221)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.TaskFactory.extractMethods(TaskFactory.java:324)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:314)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:745)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:262)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:251)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompilationContextCreator$1.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(PrecompilationContextCreator.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:519)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:487)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.maybeHandleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:415)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.visit(UnifyAst.java:402)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.HasMetaData
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 64 more
            [ERROR] at EventImpl.java(303): GWT.create(EventImpl.class)
               com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
            [ERROR] at EventImpl.java(303): (EventImpl) GWT.create(EventImpl.class)
               com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
            [ERROR] at EventImpl.java(303): final static EventImpl impl = (EventImpl) GWT.create(EventImpl.class)
               com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
            [ERROR] at EventImpl.java(42): {
  Object.$clinit();
  final static EventImpl impl = (EventImpl) GWT.create(EventImpl.class);
}
               com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
            [ERROR] at EventImpl.java(42): {
  Object.$clinit();
  final static EventImpl impl = (EventImpl) GWT.create(EventImpl.class);
}
               com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
            [ERROR] at EventImpl.java(42): com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.EventImpl.$clinit()V
               com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
      [ERROR] Compiler returned false
      [WARN] recompile failed
      [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

this is my classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 8 [1.8.0_121]"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/dropbox-core-sdk-V2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/GWT FX v0.5.0 MS 1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/gwt-charts-0.9.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/gwt-maps.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/gwt-visualization.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/gwtbootstrap3-0.9.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/gwtexporter-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/gwtphonegap-3.5.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/jackson-core-2.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/jxl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gallavie/Documents/workspace/eclipseWorkspace/kod-koma/jars/mgwt-2.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml?

Comment: I dont have one you can explain what is it? , i must have it?

Comment: pom is just project descriptor file for Maven, but it seem that you are not using Maven. It seems like a version compatibility issue, what libraries do you have on the classpath besides GWT?

Comment: Hi thank you for replay I added classpath  to my question

Comment: Could you please delete the gwt-unitCache folder to make sure gwt is not reusing any compiled files. Also if you compile with logLevel TRACE you could get better error description

Answer (score 0):

That `HasMetaData` interface was [deprecated in 2009](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/commit/4d72ede75eeaa87463734e8b1d3eecfe19442c3f) (**eight** years ago!) and [deleted in late 2014](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/commit/35ddf664a6677a8ba10bc6697126280c383ef58a) (two years ago).

This means `com.google.gwt.maps.jsio` was obsolete (a long time ago IIRC) and needs to be replaced now.

Comment: Hi thank you for replay but i dont understand replace with what

Comment: Any other supported Google Maps wrapper that works with GWT 2.8. (isn't you gwt-maps also using Google Maps API v2? which is no longer supported; I also see gwt-visualization and gwt-charts, aren't those Google APIs deprecated too? Looks like you have a bigger problem than just GWT dependencies: third-party API dependencies)

Comment: Hi thank you for replay but i dont think this my problem because I opend new project "Hello world" with GWT 2.8 and get it this error  and my new project not include google map and other libs thank you again

Comment: Then it must be a different error, that error you pasted specifically points at a class that has been removed in 2.8 (but was present in 2.7), that comes from gwt-maps.